# Magento - Script to copy attributes from SKU and add suffix

Tags: magento, attributes

i work on Magento 1.8.1CE

But now i need to replace a lot of values ....

Everything from attributes
`SKU` must be copied to `Artikelnummer`

And all vakues from `Barcode` (when not empty) should be copied to `SKU` with a suffix `-kd`

Could any help me writting a script for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Be sure to run on a testing environment first. When it is finished check the file var/log/system.log for any errors.

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';
class Upgrade extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo 'Starting upgrade script...' . PHP_EOL;
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('Artikelnummer')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('Barcode');

        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            $artikelnummer = $product->getArtikelnummer();
            $barcode = $product->getBarcode();
            if (!$artikelnummer || !$barcode)
            {
                Mage::log('Unable to update product. Skipped. SKU = ' . $product->getSku());
                continue;
            }

            // set Artikelnummer value = SKU
            $product->setArtikelnummer($product->getSku());

            // set SKU = barcode + -kd suffix
            $newBarcode = $barcode . '-kd';
            $product->setSku($newBarcode);

            $product->save();
        }

        echo 'Finished' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$shell = new Upgrade;
$shell->run();
```

Comment: should i place this as a php file in the root, and than call it from the command line?

Comment: Edited code snippet. Place that in a php file in the shell/ folder and run it from the command line.

Comment: thank you. it runs and quotes starting and finished .... but no items are changed

Comment: Anything in the log file?

Comment: Are the attribute codes in the script correct? Also, are you a dev and can you troubleshoot? Just trying to figure out what degree of instruction/technical detail to give.

Comment: i know a little bit .... but not much about script and php programming. The right attributes are `artikelnummer` and `barcode` both with a capital letter to start with

Comment: So first `sku` has to be copied to `artikelnummer`. And then `barcode` to `sku` (but only for non empty `barcode` attributes, when barcode is emty the sku should not be changed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130975/discussion-between-additionemery-and-ronny).

Comment: you still there? I now see it also changed the visibilty and the collection attribute